# Save a RDOMailItem not always executed

Tags: outlook-redemption

I wrote the following piece of code in Outlook VBA using Redeption from Dimastr to try and set the SentOn and ReceivedTime properties of a deferred email, as Outlook sets ReceivedTime on the day you click Send, but not when it is actually sent. It is based on the ItemAdd event on the sent items folder. The problem is that sometimes it works fine, but sometimes not, especially when the email is deferred to another day and in the meantime I turn off Outlook. It is like the Redemption save call were not working or were overwritten. Have you done something similar and found a solution for this?

This is de code:

```
Private Sub SentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  
  Open FILEPATH For Append As 1
  Print #1, Now & " ItemAdd Step 1: " & item.Subject & " : " & item.SentOn & " - " & item.ReceivedTime & " - " & item.DeferredDeliveryTime

  If item.DeferredDeliveryTime <> #1/1/4501# Then
  
    Print #1, Now & " ItemAdd Step 2: " & item.Subject & " : " & item.SentOn & " - " & item.ReceivedTime & " - " & item.DeferredDeliveryTime
  
    If RDOSession Is Nothing Then
      Set RDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
      RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
    End If
   
    Set sitem = RDOSession.GetMessageFromID(item.EntryID)
    sitem.SentOn = Now
    sitem.ReceivedTime = Now
    sitem.DeferredDeliveryTime = #1/1/4501#
    sitem.Save
    
    Print #1, Now & " ItemAdd Paso 3: " & sitem.Subject & " : " & sitem.SentOn & " - " & sitem.ReceivedTime & " - " & sitem.DeferredDeliveryTime
    
    Set sitem = Nothing

  End If
  
ProgramExit:
  Close #1
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  'MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line

```
 Set sitem = RDOSession.GetMessageFromID(item.EntryID)
```

with

```
 Set sitem = RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(item)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and let you know.

Comment: After doing some tests and adjustments it seems to be working fine. Thank you very much for you solution.

Answer (score 0):

The store provider sets `PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME` (SentOn) to the time that the client application called the `Send` method. It seems the issue is not related to the Redemption library. I'd suggest playing with [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) application and see how the Extended MAPI and store providers work.